# Declaring Incremental Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript

I would like to declare a set of fixed vars to be used as indicies to a large array
e.g. var age = 1, height = 2, weight = 3, name = 4, address = 5, education = 6.

I know very well that I if I used an object to store this data I would not have to declare each index, but assume for a few minutes that I need to use an array to store the data.

My problem is in in many cases I have such lists of indicies that exceed 30 or 40 in length and quite often I want to insert a new index into the middle of the list and I have to edit the list and slowly increment each existing defined value by one (or more if I insert more than one new index at a time).

How can I cleanly declare and initialise this set of vars to avoid this problem.

Could I define an object to contain them all and pass the object to an initialiser function that assigns start values to each?

What if I later wanted to minify the code and replace the variables with actual values.

Comment: `var a=[null, "age","height","weight"], values=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).map(([k,v])=>[v,k]))` now, values.height == 2 etc?

Comment: I must be able to write code such as x = a [name]; code such as x = a["name"] is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can go with typescript way.
In typescript:

```
enum Person {
 age = 1,
 height,
 weight
}
```

is equivalent of

```
var Person;

(function (Person) {
  Person[Person["age"] = 1] = "age";
  Person[Person["height"] = 2] = "height";
  Person[Person["weight"] = 3] = "weight";
})(Person || (Person = {}));
```

The rough implementation using es6 syntax is given below. A util class Enum.

**Using Proxy:**

```js
class Enum {
  constructor(args, startIndex = 0, defaultValue) {
    const em = args.split("|").reduce((m, key, index) => {
      m[(m[key] = index + startIndex)] = key;
      return m;
    }, {});
    em.value = em.key = (k) => em[k];
    return new Proxy(em, {
      get: (obj, prop) => (prop in obj ? obj[prop] : defaultValue),
    });
  }
}
const Person = new Enum("AGE|HEIGHT|WEIGHT", 2, -1);
console.log(Person); // { '2': 'AGE', '3': 'HEIGHT', '4': 'WEIGHT', AGE: 2, HEIGHT: 3, WEIGHT: 4 }

// How to use it:
let { AGE, HEIGHT, X } = Person;
console.log(AGE, HEIGHT, X); // 2, 3, -1

// To get key
if ("HEIGHT" === Person.key(3)) {
  console.log("You are right!"); // You are right
}

// To get value
if (2 === Person.value("AGE")) {
  console.log("You are right, Again!"); // You are right
}
```

**Using Basic Javascript:**

```js
const enumVars = (args, startIndex = 1) => {
  return args.split("|").reduce((m, key, index) => {
    m[(m[key] = index + startIndex)] = key;
    return m;
  }, {});
};
const Person = enumVars("AGE|HEIGHT|WEIGHT", 2);
console.log(Person); // { '2': 'AGE', '3': 'HEIGHT', '4': 'WEIGHT', AGE: 2, HEIGHT: 3, WEIGHT: 4 }

// How to use it:
let { AGE, HEIGHT } = Person;
console.log(AGE, HEIGHT); // 2, 3

// To get key

if ("HEIGHT" === Person[3]) {
  console.log("You are right!");
}
```

Comment: I downvoted when you just posted typescript, since typescript was not asked for :p removed the downvote now that you've posted a non-typescript answer :p

Comment: hahah!! i was writing util, first i added answer how to proceed. :-P since it not copy pasted. requires some effort :-D Thanks, anyways.

Comment: Haha! Please check-out my answer. I appreciated your review.